# Unable to import 'openpyxl' and 'xlsxwriter'

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I could import pandas, numpy, etc. without a problem.
But importing 'openpyxl' or 'xlsxwriter' is impossible.

- Python: 3.7.0
- openpyxl: 2.6.2
- xlsxwriter: 1.1.8

I installed 'openpyxl' and 'xlsxwriter' without any problem.[image]
 As I followed the "normal" precedure via 'pip install..' - as I've done for pandas and numpy - all packages are stored in the same file 'site-packges'

[image]

Pandas and numpy could be imported and used without any problem. But for 'openpyxl' and 'xlsxwriter' I got a warning [image]

Could you tell me, how I could solve the problem?

Comment: This is just your linter being unable to find them. They are still there and the program should run. These are warnings, not errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an Error Message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter' `

Comment: Maybe you run it inside a virtual environment, where `xlsxwriter` is not installed?

Comment: @ilja - is there wa way to get the path which Python uses to find the "xlswriter" package?  Looks like a Path-Error to me...

Comment: @MaxMark, run `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` to get the interpreter path (inside your **script**). You can not find out the path of the package, because it cannot be imported ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As beeing stated by @Jmonsky (see comment) it's just a warning! 
It works now!